# Display text for drag and drop images VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop

I am developing a simple SQL generator for images. I am having issues getting texts to be displayed in a textbox when I drag pictures into a PictureBox. Am I doing anything wrong? I want a situation when I drag the image into the PictureBox, the textbox shown in blue should display: 'SELECT FROM EMPLOYEE;'. I need help to get this code working. My code is displayed below.

[image]

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    '' picDropTarget.AllowDrop = True
    picAccept.AllowDrop = True


End Sub

Private Sub picSELECT_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles picSELECT.MouseDown, picEMPLOYEE.MouseDown
    ' Start the drag if it's the left mouse button.
    If (e.Button = MouseButtons.Left) Then
        Dim source As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
        picSELECT.DoDragDrop(source.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy)
        'Added this line to show 
        'txtSQL.Text = "SELECT"
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub picAccept_DragEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles picAccept.DragEnter
    ' See if this is a copy and the data includes an image.
    If (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap) AndAlso
       (e.AllowedEffect And DragDropEffects.Copy) <> 0) _
    Then
        ' Allow this.
        'e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All
    Else
        ' Don't allow any other drop.
        '   e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub picAccept_DragDrop(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles picAccept.DragDrop, picSELECT.DragDrop, picEMPLOYEE.DragDrop
    Dim bm As Bitmap = DirectCast(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, True), Bitmap)
    picAccept.Image = bm

End SubEnd Class
```

Comment: Where in your drop method do you set the textbox content? I see you are setting the image property of something, but where is the textbox being changed? What should appear in the textbox and what currently gets populated in there?

Comment: I have tried different drop method to hold that content but nothing seems to work. Something like:  SELECT FROM EMPLOYEE. I want to try and achieve that before adding columns to work with it.

Comment: Still don't know what content goes in what textbox. If you want help over ip, you have to be more descriptive in what you have, what your goals are, and what you are struggling with.

Comment: I have rephrased my question @blaze_125

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextBox1.Text = "select from EMPLOYEES"
```

Here's a fully working minimal sample. You can copy/paste the below, drop a file into the PictureBox at the bottom of the form, and the TextBox at the top will get populated with text.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim txtbx As New TextBox
    Dim pctbx As New PictureBox
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        txtbx.Dock = DockStyle.Top
        pctbx.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom
        pctbx.BackColor = Color.AntiqueWhite
        pctbx.AllowDrop = True
        Controls.Add(txtbx)
        Controls.Add(pctbx)
        AddHandler pctbx.DragEnter, AddressOf pctbx_DragEnter
        AddHandler pctbx.DragDrop, AddressOf pctbx_DragDrop

    End Sub

    Private Sub pctbx_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All
    End Sub

    Private Sub pctbx_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)
        txtbx.Text = "select from employees where id = "
    End Sub



End Class
```

Comment: But which method should capture each of this drags and drop events??

Comment: that's up to you to decide. if you want the textbox to populate with new content every time something is dropped, then put that in your current drop method.